# How do I make a PGP key?

Tags: openpgp

How do I make a PGP key? The description says  "Open Passwords and Encryption Keys".But I don't find it in elementary.

Please explain the procedure step by step.

*EDIT*:

I am asking for GUI way, I know [CLI method](https://askubuntu.com/a/77194/439451)

Answer (score 1):

That GUI tool belong to seahorse (GNOME front end for GnuPG) package, so try installing it:

```
sudo apt-get install seahorse
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer OP's question in detail.